# Delete a exist doc throw a FileNotFoundException?

Tags: elasticsearch

1.I search the doc,resp:

```
"_index": "index-15",
"_type": "member",
"_id": "179751941",
"_score": 1,
"_routing": "15375",
"_source": {xxx}
```

2.I use `DELETE` method to delete a doc,and throw a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ip:port/index-15/member/179751941
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1835)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
```

Comment: You need to specify the routing parameter as well `?routing=15375`

Comment: @Val,Thank you,but sometimes i can delete doc successful,why?

Comment: probably because those docs have been created without routing in the first place? Sounds possible?

Comment: @Val,Thank you, Here is another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069445/search-slow-when-high-concurrency) need for your help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a document using the `routing` parameter, which seems to be your case according to the sample document you're showing, then you also need to specify the routing parameter `?routing=15375` when deleting your document.